# Rabbitmq Priority Queue Write Performance Reduced as number of priorities increases

Tags: rabbitmq, priority-queue

I am using Rabbitmq 3.7.3 with Java client 5.1.2 [amqp-client-5.1.2.jar] for priority queue. In my usecase I will be having maximum of 60 priorities in a single non persistence queue where only few upto 10-15 will be mostly used.

Case 1. If I have defined a queue to have 10 priorities, and messages ranging from 0 to 9 priorities are pushed to the queue, I am getting 12500 writes per second.

Case 2. If I have defined a queue to have 60 priorities, and messages ranging from 0-9 priorities are pushed to the queue, I am getting 4200 writes per second.

Case 3: If I have defined a queue to have 250 priorities, and messages ranging from 0-9 priorities are pushed to the queue, I am getting only 1500 writes per second.

What observed here is, as and when we increase the priorities capacity of a queue, though only very few being used, the write performance degrades.

Below is the code snippet: [Writes are done using single thread]

```
import com.rabbitmq.client.ConnectionFactory;
import com.rabbitmq.client.Connection;
import com.rabbitmq.client.Channel;
import com.rabbitmq.client.AMQP.BasicProperties;
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;

public class Write implements Runnable{
    int start;
    int count;
    int end;
    private long unixTime;
    private long timeTaken;
    private long totalTimeTaken;
    private long totalRequests;
    private long minLatency;
    private long maxLatency;
    private double avgLatency;
    private FileOutputStream out;

    int parity = 1;
    int ndnc = 0;
    int mnp = 1001;
    int blist = 0;
    String value;
    ConnectionFactory factory;
    Connection connection;
    Channel channel;
    String QUEUE_NAME;  



    public  Write(int s, int c){
        this.start = s;
        this.count = c;
        this.end = this.count;
        this.totalTimeTaken = 0;
        this.totalRequests = 0;
        this.minLatency = 1000000;
        this.maxLatency = 0;

        try{    
            this.QUEUE_NAME = "queuedata_4";
            this.factory = new ConnectionFactory();
            factory.setHost("192.168.1.100");
            factory.setUsername("user");
            factory.setPassword("pass");
            this.connection = factory.newConnection();
            this.channel = this.connection.createChannel();
            Map<String, Object> args = new HashMap<String, Object>();
            args.put("x-max-priority", 60);
            this.channel.queueDeclare(QUEUE_NAME, false, false, false, args);
        }catch(Exception e){
            System.out.println("Create Exception"+e);
        }   
    }

    public void run(){
        String message;
        byte[] data = null;

        for(int k=this.start; k<=(this.end); k++){
            message = "Message_" + k;
            unixTime = System.nanoTime();
            try{
                    this.channel.basicPublish(
                        "", 
                        this.QUEUE_NAME, 
                        new BasicProperties.Builder()
                        .deliveryMode(1)
                        .priority(k%10+1)
                        .build(),
                        message.getBytes("UTF-8")
                    );
                }catch(Exception e){
                    System.out.println("New connection made"+e);
            }

            timeTaken = System.nanoTime() - unixTime;
            totalTimeTaken += timeTaken;
            if(timeTaken < minLatency){
                minLatency = timeTaken;
            }
            if(timeTaken > maxLatency){
                maxLatency = timeTaken;
            }
            totalRequests ++;
        }

        avgLatency = totalTimeTaken / totalRequests;
        System.out.println("TotalReqs:" + totalRequests + " 
        TotalTime:" + ((float)totalTimeTaken/1000000.0) + " 
        MinLatency:" + ((float)minLatency/1000000.0) + " MaxLatency:" 
        + ((float)maxLatency/1000000.0) + " AvgLatency:" + 
        ((float)avgLatency/1000000.0));
        try{
            channel.close();
                connection.close(); 
        }catch(Exception e){
             System.out.println("Close Exception");
        }
    }



}
```

Comment: Hi! Have you read [the official documentation](https://www.rabbitmq.com/priority.html)? It states `If priority queues are desired, we recommend using between 1 and 10. Currently using more priorities will consume more resources (Erlang processes).` That may be what you ran into?

Comment: Yes. Thanks for your response. But I am not seeing more than 100% CPU utilized at the server side. Where it is blocking? How can I handle this scenario?  Are there any other messaging system which support priority queues with better performance?

Comment: I don't know for sure in your case, but message queue softwares I know enforces limits on the number of priorities per queue (e.g. QPid, ActiveMQ). That's probably for good reasons. RabbitMQ isn't so rude, but highly discourages having many priorities per queue. You may have to rethink your software to not rely that much on priority queues instead. Unless somebody knows a message queue that have better support for priority queues. Sorry :/